# NodeJS - Converting GPX to Geojson return empty array

Tags: node.js, geojson, jsdom, domparser, gpx

I have a form where the user upload a GPX file and is then converted into Geojson, I use [mapbox/togeojson](https://github.com/mapbox/togeojson) module to achieve it and I have this code :

```
const togeojson = require ('togeojson')
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const fs = require ('fs');
const DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
module.exports = (express, Courses) => {

var courses_router = express.Router()

courses_router.route('/')
    .post(upload.single('gpxFile'),(req, res, next) => {
        let file = req.file
        if (file) {
            console.log("Uploaded : " + file.originalname + " to " + file.path)
            fs.readFile(file.path, (err, data) => {
                // let gpxJSDOM = new JSDOM(data)
                let gpx = new DOMParser().parseFromString(file.path, 'text/xml');
                let converted = togeojson.gpx(gpx)

            })
        }

        // var path = utils.ModifyString(req.body.title)
        // return false;
        // course_container.CreateCourses(Courses, req, res, path)
    })
```

When I log the result of `converted`, I get : `{ type: 'FeatureCollection', features: [] }`, which looks like Geojson structure but is not filled with the corresponding datas (I have checked on an [online convertor](https://mapbox.github.io/togeojson/) that my GPX datas are good)
I also tried using JSDOM as this [tutorial](https://www.devout.io/working-with-gpx-data-using-nodejs-mongodb/) suggests but with no results, I guess there is some data manipulation that is wrong on my code but I have no clue where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer ! I didn't need the read the file, I just had to get the path of the uploaded file and then pass it to the `new DOMParser()` function to finally be converted in GeoJson (And didn't need JSDOM at all)

```
const course_container = require('./../../containers/CourseContainer');
const utils = require('./../../../utils/functions')
const togeojson = require ('togeojson')
const fs = require ('fs');
const DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
module.exports = (express, Courses) => {

    var courses_router = express.Router()

    courses_router.route('/')
        .post(upload.single('gpxFile'),(req, res, next) => {
            var file = req.file
            if (file) {
                var absolutePath = path.resolve(file.path);
                var gpx = new DOMParser().parseFromString(fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, 'utf8'));
                var geoJson = togeojson.gpx(gpx)
            }

            var course_path = utils.ModifyString(req.body.title)
            course_container.CreateCourses(Courses, req, res, course_path, geoJson)
        })
```